# Cannot see whole script in console

Tags: javascript, console

I'd like to edit a script inside the Chrome developer tools, but I cannot find a way to open it completely. There are 3 dots at the end, as shown in the screenshot. How can I open these kinds of longer scripts and edit them live ?[Dots before ending tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQOlF.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you edit Javascript in the browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2558346/how-do-you-edit-javascript-in-the-browser)

Answer (score 1):

Head to `sources` section in the dev tools, Use `ctr+p` option, it'll open up a search bar and search the file name you want to open and select the script file from the results.

Comment: It's not a separate file, it's inside the index.html.

Comment: Navigate to the index HTML from the sidebar in the same panel, otherwise for index.html just view source by right-clicking on the page and select the view source option